# Generating a new variable using the difference between 2 existing variable.

Tags: stata

I have two variables named "systolic bp" and "diastolic bp", and I want to get "systolic bp - diastolic bp" for a new variable called "Pulse pressure", but the Stata said there's "too many variables specified". Is there any way to solve this???

thanks in advance

Comment: If that is what you typed, you must use variable names, not variable labels or other text. But you are not giving you complete and exact code -- in a programming forum.

Answer (score 0):

Before opening your dataset try to increase the memory size:

```
set mem 100m
set matsize 800
```